# getting EOFError when using input()?

Tags: python

my script is for some reason giving an eoferror? I am making a script that's a messaging system for a helpdesk because I want to help people with their problems with my main program live. I was just finishing up the final touches when all of a sudden input doesn't work anymore without throwing me EOF errors?? here's my code. it asks for a name before spawning the message sending gui while it goes into a while loop to print the sent messages with the usernames at the start in green

```
from sendgui import *
import sys
from multiprocessing import Process
from termcolor import colored
import socket
def initinite():
    name = input("username: ")
    msgsendr(name)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    proc = Process(target=initinite)
    proc.start()

    ClientSocket = socket.socket()
    host = socket.gethostname()
    port = 8080

    print(colored('Waiting for connection', 'yellow'))
    try:
        ClientSocket.connect((host, 8080))
    except socket.error as e:
        print(colored("ERROR!", "red"), colored("could not connect. the server may be offline or you don't have an internet connection", "yellow"))
        input("press enter to continue")
        sys.exit("could not connect")
    print(colored("connected!", "green"))
    while True:
        Response = ClientSocket.recv(1024)
        Response = Response.decode()
        name = Response.split(": ")[0]
        mess = Response.split(": ")[1]
        name = colored(name, "green")
        print(name+": "+mess)

    ClientSocket.close()
```

someone requested for the full traceback so here:

```
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*redacted*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\*redacted*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\*redacted*\Desktop\e program files\recievegui.py", line 7, in initinite
    name = input("username: ")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: ok will do. thanks for telling me!

Comment: Done! hope this helps!

Comment: Are you running the script from an IDE like VSCode? By default they don't allow you to supply input.

Comment: I'm using pycharm which comes with a terminal that opens up its not the ide because input works on other programs